# Does using memset and malloc conflict?

Tags: c, malloc, memset

```
char* buf;
buf = malloc(BUFSIZ);
memset(buf ,0 , BUFSIZ);
```

I think that memset initializes the buf variable with size of BUFSIZ, but malloc also allocates a block of size BUFSIZE of memory and returning a pointer to the beginning of the block to the variable buf... I do not know if memset can be used for pointers because it initialize data with size BUFSIZE but we do not poit to it.... 
Can you suggests anything to fix this problem, thanks

---

Hi all and thanks for the answers. So I understood that the problem generally comes from the fact that malloc can fail and then the buf will point to NULL.
And maybe the best way to fix the flaw of the code is to check if buf is equals to null?

```
char* buf;
buf = malloc(BUFSIZ);
if(buf!=null)
{
memset(buf ,0 , BUFSIZ);
}
```

---

Maybe the best way to fix the flaw of the code is to check if buf is equals to null?

```
char* buf;
buf = malloc(BUFSIZ);
if(buf!=null)
{
memset(buf ,0 , BUFSIZ);
}
```

Is it possible in practice malloc to fail? Or it is just a theory?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. What problem are you trying to solve and what makes you think there's a problem?

Comment: The code fails to check the return state of `malloc`. You can get away with that on linux (because of over-commit and the OOM killer) and on other platforms with protected memory (provided that segfault-and-die is an acceptable response) but is is a bad practice in general.

Comment: "Is it possible in practice malloc to fail? Or it is just a theory?" - if there is no free memory, it will fail... in practice. What for a question.

Answer (score 3):

There's just no problem with that code, except the fact that you don't check for NULL after allocating memory.

Note that you can also use calloc to allocate memory, initialized with 0, so you can avoid the memset call:

```
char * buf;

buf = calloc( 1, BUFSIZ );

if( buf == NULL )
{
    /* Error management */
}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending calloc.  But don't pollute a beautiful language with that hideous cast.  =)

Comment: The cast may be needed in some case, even if it doesn't look very nice... But sure you know that... ; )

Comment: +1 for not using sizeof(char) as the first argument. -1 for the cast. The cast is superfluous, dangerous, and TOTALLY WRONG. c != c++. @Macmade: please explain why it "would be needed".

Comment: The cast is never needed.  You seem to be confusing C with some other language that looks sort of vaguely like C. =)

Comment: I was thinking about C++ compatibility, you were right. I work most of the time on C projects which needs such a compatibility, so casting malloc is a kind of reflex. But wrong in that case, you're right. : )

Comment: The cast is pointless since you have declared buff as char * already, so you are just sucking CPU cycles, but more then likely the compiler optimized that line out. but if(! buff = calloc(1,BUFSIZE)) is a better statement IMO

Comment: The cast does not "suck CPU cycles", except for a few hundred while parsing. For the human reader, it costs a fraction of a second to read and understand it (and a few minutes of anger). Loss of value for the dishes and furniture varies per case.

Comment: @wildplasser Explain why it is "dangerous, and TOTALLY WRONG".

Comment: It is dangerous because it hides errors detected by the compiler. The obvious error to be hidden is failure to include <stdlib.h>, which would cause the prototype for malloc() et.al. to be defaulted to "int". This certainly fails terribly when sizeof (int) != sizeof (void*), such as on most 64 bit platforms. Including stdlib and trusting on a (void*) to be cast to *any* pointer type will solve any problem. Not including stdlib will cause (at least) an error message/diagnostic.

Comment: @wildplasser IIRC, implicit function declarations are forbidden in C99, although I guess you make a valid point for C89(even though I'm guessing warning flags would detect that).

Comment: The spirit of C is to allow previous versions of "the standard" to coexist. Implicit int is one of them. If you don't want it: increase the compiler's sensitivity to standard violations. Casting malloc's return type does exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that malloc does not fail and return a NULL pointer, this is fine.

`buf` points to the start of the allocated memory, which is BUFSIZ bytes big. memset sets BUFSIZ bytes to 0 starting at the memory pointed to by `buf`.

Comment: So in the end buf will point to a block of memory with size BUFSIZ which block will have only 0-s in it?

Answer (score 0):

`memset` is the equivalent of:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n) {
    char *ss = (char *)s;
    while (n--)
        *ss++ = c;
    return s;
}
```

So, yes, it can be (and is) used in pointers. It sets `s`, and `(n-1)` bytes following `s`, to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* buf; // u declare a pointer, pointing to some random memory area
buf = malloc(BUFSIZ); // you allocate BUFSIZ bytes on the heap and set buf to point to that area.
memset( buf, 0, BUFSIZE ); // the area where buf points to are all set to 0, all BUFSIZE of them.
```

seems pretty straightforward.

memset is a bit like:

```
for (unsigned char *p = buf; p < buf + BUFSIZE; *p++ = '\0' );
```